Policies' directory not present in saved checkpoint
I'm using RayRL Lib, and after switching to the new API version, the checkpoint directory no longer includes the policies folder. Why this might be happening?
Currently, the checkpoints contain the following directories and files:
env_runner
learner_group
algorithm_state.pkl
class_and_ctor_args.pkl
rllib_checkpoint.json

Any help would be appreciated!
